# django one to many relation

Tags: django

im having a two models one is companyusers and the other is qualification
and one user has many qualifications 
now i need to enter qualifications while creating the user in admin how do i do that?

i have tried to keep many to many field in the users model but in vain...
the qualifications that are related to other user is populating in the fields where as i need to create new qualification for the new user.

code follows..

```
class Qualification(models.Model):
    qualification = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    max_marks = models.IntegerField(max_length=50)
    marks_obtained = models.IntegerField(max_length=50)
    qualifying_year = models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True)

class CompanyUser(User):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    qualifications = models.ManyToManyField(Qualification)
```

here is the company user details..

> {"username":"steve","position":"Senior Engineer", "date_of_birth": "1986-05-14"}
>
> {"qualification":"secondary school", "max_marks":"1000", "marks_obtained":"850", "qualifying_year":"1990"}
>
> {"qualification":"undergraduation", "max_marks":"750", "marks_obtained":"680", "qualifying_year":"1992"}
>
> {"qualification":"postgraduation", "max_marks":"1500", "marks_obtained":"1280", "qualifying_year":"1997"}

Comment: Should a qualification be related to exactly one user? Or can several users have the same qualification? In the later case ManyToManyField is just right, since an CompanyUser has many qualification and one qualification can be hold by many CompanyUsers.

Comment: @jOker --- since qualification contains marks/score obtained by user it should be related to **exactly one** user, and the no of qualifications vary from user to user. say user1 is having 2 qualifications then user2 can have 2 or more than 2 qualifications.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The One-To-Many relation you are looking for doesn't exist in Django. It's not needed, since you can do it the other way round: With a ForeignKey relation from the qualification to the user. According to your example, you would define the models as follows:

```
class Qualification(models.Model):
    qualification = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    max_marks = models.IntegerField(max_length=50)
    marks_obtained = models.IntegerField(max_length=50)
    qualifying_year = models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('CompanyUser', related_name='qualifications')

class CompanyUser(User):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

So, there is no relation specified from CompanyUser to Qualification but you have a ForeignKey relation from Qualification to CompanyUser (i.e. each qualification belongs to one user, but multiple qualifications can belong to the same user). Django automatically maintains the backwards relation from CompanyUser to Qualification, which is the One-To-Many relation you are looking for. By the option `related_name` of the ForeignKey you can specify a meaningful name for the backwards relation (in this case 'qualifications'). You can now simply access the Qualifications on a CompanyUser object with the attribute `user.qualifications`.

In the admin you would first create a new CompanyUser and then an arbitrary number of Qualifications which you assign to this user via the ForeignKey.

Be sure to read about that stuff in the Django docs section about [Model relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#relationships).

Comment: @joker thanks for the answer it was helpful, but i have another problem with the above solution. after creating CompanyUser i need to create qualifications for that user. but i need to create qualifications while creating company user. how can i do that.

Comment: You obviously have to create the CompanyUser first, since the Qualifications rely on its ID as ForeignKey. So, the user must be already in the database when the qualification is saved. There is no built-in way to do both actions in one step in the admin. However, if you're writing the app by yourself, you can create a form to input data for the CompanyUser as well as its Qualifications, send the data to the server and use a view function to save the user first and its qualifications after that.

Comment: @j0ker-- thanks that was really helpful. i was thinking whether there was any built-in functionality.

Comment: does this also take care of the condition when multiple users have same qualification?